# Laravel - Populate a chart with data from database function improvement

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts

I have an admin dashboard that shows a Line Chart with how many users registered each month.
I am getting the data from the database and it seems to all work fine but the function is quite large and I wanted to know if there was a more optimal and efficient way to get and return the same data?

I am assigning this function to a variable and passing it to my view.

```
// Get Monthly Registered Users This year
public function monthlyRegisteredUsers()
{
    $janUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 1)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $febUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 2)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $marUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 3)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $aprUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 4)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $mayUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 5)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $junUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 6)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $julUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 7)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $augUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 8)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $sepUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 9)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $octUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 10)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $novUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 11)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $decUsers = User::whereMonth('created_at', 12)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
    $data  = [$janUsers, $febUsers, $marUsers, $aprUsers, $mayUsers, $junUsers, $julUsers, $augUsers, $sepUsers, $octUsers, $novUsers, $decUsers ];
    return $data;
}
```

All it does is get the number of registered users each month and assigns it to a variable, then I return the array with the number of users each month.
Can this be improved?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_map and range to make this code much shorter:

```
public function monthlyRegisteredUsers()
{
  return array_map(function($month){
    return User::whereMonth('created_at', $month)->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))->count();
  }, range(1,12))
}
```

And I think you can use a group by to just run one query, let me update my answer by a better query.

```
public function monthlyRegisteredUsers()
{
  $counts = User::select(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) month, count(*) as count'))
            ->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
            ->pluck('count', 'month')
            ->toArray();
   return array_map(function($month) use ($counts){
            return Arr::get($counts, $month, 0);
        }, range(1,12));
}
```

Comment: Hey Reza, thank you so much! It worked perfect! Really appreciate you taking the time to help! Could I adapt this same function to get subscribers per month also?

Comment: Yes. Sure. You can add new conditions by where() method.